# Wagtail - Can't render orderables on my HTML

Tags: python, html, wagtail

I want to extract the name of my snippets to put it on my blog in the form of a list, but they just don't appear.

I have coded the snippets, console does not throws any error, i have created the respective snippets on the admin panel and then added them onto my detail_blog_page, and made the respective code to put it on the HTML page model, but it just does not appear, im following [the instructions of this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AZuyqG11hcE&list=PLMQHMcNi6ocsS8Bfnuy_IDgJ4bHRRrvub&index=21) to make and add the snippets.

my blog listing page it's actually my Home page, and my blog detail page it's located on the same template file as the home page one, so maybe there's where the error is, but i can't figure it out.

When i try to pull the info of the blog detail page onto the home page, there's no problem, it brings all the info, the images and text, but when i try to pull the snippets ot the blog detail page, simply it doesn't bring anything, I tried it on the home page too, but didn't work either.

[image]

Home/models.py

```
from django.db import models

from wagtail.models import Page, Orderable
from modelcluster.fields import ParentalKey
from wagtail.snippets.edit_handlers import SnippetChooserPanel
from wagtail.core.fields import RichTextField, StreamField
from wagtail.admin.edit_handlers import (InlinePanel, FieldPanel, PageChooserPanel, MultiFieldPanel, StreamFieldPanel)
from wagtail.images.edit_handlers import ImageChooserPanel

from wagtail.snippets.models import register_snippet


from streams import blocks

class CategoriasOrdenables(Orderable):
   """Nos deja seleccionar uno o más categorias para la noticia"""

   page = ParentalKey("home.BlogDetailPage", related_name="categorias")
   categoria = models.ForeignKey(
       "home.Categorias",
       on_delete=models.CASCADE,
   )

   panels = [
       SnippetChooserPanel("categoria"),
   ]

class Categorias(models.Model):
   """Snippets"""

   name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   website = models.URLField(blank=True, null=True)
   image = models.ForeignKey(
       "wagtailimages.Image",
       on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
       null=True,
       blank=True,
       related_name="+",
   )

   panels = [
       MultiFieldPanel(
           [
               FieldPanel("name"),
               ImageChooserPanel("image"),
           ],
           heading="Nombre e imagen"
       ),
       MultiFieldPanel(
           [
               FieldPanel("website"),
           ],
           heading="Links"
       )
   ]

   def __str__(self):
       """String repr of this class."""
       return self.name

   class Meta:  # noqa
       verbose_name = "Categoría"
       verbose_name_plural = "Categorías"


register_snippet(Categorias)

class HomePage(Page):
   """home page model"""
   template = "home/home_page.html"
   max_count = 1

   banner_cta = models.ForeignKey(
       "wagtailcore.Page",
       null=True,
       blank=True,
       on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
       related_name="+"
   )

   content = StreamField(
       [
           ("cta", blocks.CTABlock())
       ],
       null = True,
       blank = True
   ) 

   content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
       PageChooserPanel("banner_cta"),
       StreamFieldPanel("content"),
   ]

   def get_context(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
       """Adding custom stuff to our context."""
       context = super().get_context(request, *args, **kwargs)
       context["posts"] = BlogDetailPage.objects.live().public()
       context["categorias"] = Categorias.objects.all()
       return context

   class Meta:
       verbose_name = "Home Page"
       verbose_name_plural="Home Pages"

class BlogDetailPage(Page):
   """Blog detail page."""

   custom_title = models.CharField(
       max_length=100,
       blank=False,
       null=False,
       help_text='Overwrites the default title',
   )
   
   blog_image = models.ForeignKey(
       "wagtailimages.Image",
       blank=False,
       null=True,
       related_name="+",
       on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
   )

   content = StreamField(
       [
           ("title_and_text", blocks.TitleAndTextBlock()),
           ("full_richtext", blocks.RichTextBlock()),
           ("cards", blocks.CardBlock()),
           ("cta", blocks.CTABlock()),
       ],
       null=True,
       blank=True,
   )

   content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
       FieldPanel("custom_title"),
       ImageChooserPanel("blog_image"),
       MultiFieldPanel(
           [
               InlinePanel("categorias", label="Categoría", min_num=1)
           ],
           heading="Categoría(s)"
       ),
       StreamFieldPanel("content"),
   ]

   class Meta:
       verbose_name = "Pagina de noticia"
       verbose_name_plural="Pagina de noticias"
```

home/blog_detail_page.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% load wagtailimages_tags wagtailcore_tags %}

{% block content %}
   {% image self.blog_image fill-1200x300 as banner %}
   <img src="{{ banner.url }}" alt="{{ banner.alt }}" style='width: 100%; height: auto;'>

   <div class="container mt-5 mb-5">
       <div class="text-center">
           <h1>{{ self.custom_title }}</h1>
           {% comment %} SNIPPETS {% endcomment %}
           <ul>
               {% for iter in self.categoria.all %}
               <li>
                   {{ iter.categoria.name }}
               </li>
               {% endfor %}
           </ul>

           </p>
           
       </div>
   </div>

   <div class="container">
       <div class="row">
           <div class="col-lg-8 offset-lg-2">
               {% for block in self.content %}
                   {% include_block block %}
               {% endfor %}
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>
{% endblock %}
```

home/home_page.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% load wagtailimages_tags %}

{% block content %}

    <div class="contenedor tarjetas mt-4 mb-4">
        {% for post in posts %}
            <div class="fila_tarjetas clearfix">
                <div class="col_tarjeta_img">
                    {% image post.blog_image fill-450x450 as blog_img %}
                    <a href="{{ post.url }}">
                        <img class="tarjeta_imagen" src="{{ blog_img.url }}" alt="{{ blog_img.alt }}">
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col_tarjeta_texto">
                    <a class="tarjeta_titulo" href="{{ post.url }}">
                        <h3>{{ post.custom_title }}</h3>
                        {# @todo add a summary field to BlogDetailPage; make it a RichTextField with only Bold and Italic enabled. #}
                            {% comment %} SNIPPETS {% endcomment %}
                            {% for iter in self.categoria.all %}
                                {{ iter.categoria.name }}
                            {% endfor %}
                        <div class="tarjeta_contenido"> 
                            {{ post.content }} 
                        </div>

                        <a href="{{ post.url }}" class="leer_mas">Leer más &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; > ></a>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

I have tried changing "categoria" for "categorias", but didn't work either.

```
{% for iter in self.categorias.all %}
   {{ iter.categorias.name }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `related_name` argument on `page = ParentalKey("home.BlogDetailPage", related_name="categorias")` will make a relation called `categorias` available on the BlogDetailPage model, so `self.categorias.all` is correct (not `self.categoria.all`).

This will give you a queryset of `CategoriasOrdenables` objects. To go from that to the `Categorias` object, you need to access the `categoria` property. Therefore, your final code should be:

```
{% for iter in self.categorias.all %}
   {{ iter.categoria.name }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Hi sorry for the inconvenience, yes, this works but on the Blog_detail_page, the problem is that this won't work on my Home page at all, as far as i understood, the orderables don't work that way, so i switched to normal snippets, and then i made it work, maybe it was the context and something on the lines of
`{% for iter in post.categorias.all %}
   {{ iter.categoria.name }}
{% endfor %}`
Should work, ill try it myself later with a branch that i saved for this problem in specific.

Comment: Yes, on the homepage `self` refers to the homepage object, so you need `post.categorias.all` instead.